# Matplotlib indexing error on plotting

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, indexing

I have basicaly the following script. But it fails during running with the following error`TypeError: 'Figure' object does not support indexing`
 on line `axarr[0].plot(x,y)`. I have try to search around but found a similar error with with creating subplots... And i only adding / replacing data (I'm not sure since it is a copy of a matlab file while i don't have matlab).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
for idx in range(1, 10):
    a = 1 + (idx - 1) / 10

    y = a ** x

    axarr, fig = plt.subplots(1,1)
    axarr[0].plot(x,y)
    axarr.axis([0, 4, 0, 85])
    axarr[0].grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Probably i get this error because i use a figure in a loop but it looks that it fails on iteration 1 all ready. So what do i wrong or what could better so that this works(with almost equal to matlab file see part of script below)?
I hope somebody can help.

The matlab file equal sample is this:

```
x = 0:0.01:4;
for idx = 1:10 
a = 1 + (idx-1)/10;

y = a.^x;
z = 2 * y
subplot(111)
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x(1:400),z)
axis([0 4 0 85])
pause
hold off

end
```

Comment: You have the figure and axes the wrong way around -- it should be `fix,axarr = plt.subplots(1,1)` (you can skip the `1,1` part.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The return of `plt.subplots` is a tuple of `(Figure, array of Axes)`. The asssignment has hence to be

   ```
   fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1,1)
   ```
2. The above does not completely solve the problem, as you would then end up with a similar error (`TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing`). This is due to the fact that by default `plt.subplots` reduces the `array of Axes` to a single axes in case only one column and one row are used.
   This behaviour is controlled by the `squeeze` argument. Valid ways to use `plt.subplots` are thus

   ```
   fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1,1)
   axarr.plot(x,y)
   ```

   or

   ```
   fig, axarr  = plt.subplots(1,1, squeeze=False)
   axarr[0,0].plot(x,y)
   ```

   Note that you wouldn't need need `1,1` as argument, as those are the defaults.

Comment: So if the subplot is `(n,1)`, where `n` could equal 1 and you want to iterate through different things to plot all of the indices would become `axarr[j, 0]`

Comment: squeeze=False makes a big difference!